# Split up single commit into multiple commits in existing git history

Tags: git, azure-devops

Recently I migrated an existing code base from tfs to azure devops git. Due to a number of obstacles the last ~20 commits did not migrate successfully. Because of time constraints I decided to simply copy the latest code base onto the last successfully migrated git commit and commit this as a new commit. Since then we have been working on top of this commit.

Now however I have managed to retrieve the commits that were skipped during this migration process.And I am hoping to fix the history of the git commits. I am however aware of the golden rule of git, that you should not mess with history once it has been committed.

My questions therefore are:

- When I fix the history in the master branch (all omitted changed are in a single branch), will I be able to push these changes to origin?
- When these changes are pushed to origin, will they automatically retrieved when others do a pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Will you be able to push these changes to origin?*

That depends how *origin* is configured.
The syntax you would use is

```sh
git push -f origin <commit id>:master
```

to do a forced push. However some servers prohibit this for non-admin roles, for obvious reasons.

---

*When these changes are pushed to origin, will they automatically be retrieved when others do a pull?*

They'll be retrieved. The real question is whether their local commits will apply.  The answer to this is less clear to me. I believe it may depend on the nature of the original commit.

You can test this for yourself locally of course. Set up a local branch `mastertmp` that's a copy of the old master's HEAD.

```
git checkout -b mastertmp <commit id of current master>
```

Set up another branch that tracks it:

```sh
git checkout -b worktmp -t mastertmp
```

(Maybe add some more commits to `worktmp` for authenticity. Not necessary.)
Now "rework" `mastertmp` by pointing it at your proposed new history

```
git checkout mastertmp
git reset --hard <commit id of reworked master>
```

Now change branch back to `worktmp` and pull.

```
git checkout worktmp
git pull --rebase
```

If this works, then there is no reason why it will not work for your colleagues. It doesn't matter to the logic whether you `worktmp` is tracking a local or a remote branch.

Note: To keep track of which branch is tracking which, use the command `git branch -vv`.